# Using a node.js app with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, deployment

My goal is this: JS but server-side. My solution, the obvious, node.js. I've used node.js quiet a bit. Mainly for an application, not a web server. The only reason I need to do server-side JS is that I need to use a library that connects to the [Discord API](https://discordapp.com). So I have a little test `.js` file with my node.js in it. It just prints text if it works. Basic. What I need it to do is whenever someone goes to https://example.com/something, it runs the node.js script and if the script ends up with printing "hello", then https://example.com/something will say "hello".

I've done some research on this, I've found ways to deploy a node.js app, which I know how to do. I can't really find anything that I'm looking for though.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/synopsis.html#synopsis_example

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov would I be able to specify a specific address instead of an IP?

Comment: You can use a domain name or IP address.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov ok so that would include the `/something` in my example that I can include right? because thats the main part

Comment: You will need to add  `const url = require('url');` and have something like `const pathName =url.parse(request.url).pathname;` and `if (pathName == '/somehting') { your code here }`.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov just tried that it only works at https://example.com, not at https://example.com/something. code: `var http = require("http")
var url = require("url")

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"})

  const pathName = url.parse(req.url).pathname
console.log(pathName)
  if (pathName === "html.php") {
    res.end("working?")
  }
}).listen(80)`

Comment: I will post the full code example in an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use express to run a webserver on nodejs

1. Install express by running "npm install express" in your project folder through command prompt
2. Create a `app.js` file with the following code

   ```
       var express = require('express'); // load the express library
       var app = express(); // create an instance of express
       var child_process = require('child_process'); //load the child_process module

       app.get("/something", function(req, res) { // Setup a router which listens to the site http://localhost/something
           child_process.fork("./yourCodeFile.js"); // Launch your code file
       });

       app.listen(80);
   ```
3. Run `node app.js` to listen to web connections

Then you put your code into the yourCodeFile.js which has to be be in the same folder as the app.js file, even better you could just write all your code in the app.js code as long as you keep it inside the function inside app.get

Comment: I do believe he said `Note: I don't want to have to do node file.js in command prompt.`  ??  If he has to "Run `node app.js`" how is this different?

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this. and @Zak, I think it'll be fine I don't think theres a way around that part :P

Comment: Instead of `child_process.fork("code.js")`, can I just have my code right there?

Comment: Yep you could just put your code there, and it does work with apache but you need to setup a reverse proxy http://www.slate.com/blogs/outward/2015/08/10/transgender_military_service_lessons_from_around_the_world.html

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at cloud-based lambda functions and platforms like [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html), which run a script in response to an HTTP request. They are relatively new and the architecture used to support this is being called "serverless", which is a simple term, albeit a bit of a misnomer. There are various tools out there to help you build these systems, such as the similarly named [Serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) framework, though you can typically still use more traditional server frameworks that you are probably more comfortable with. Either way, you are not responsible for managing any server, including starting it or stopping it.

In terms of constructing a response that you are happy with, you can of course respond with any arbitrary string you want. See the AWS example of a [Node.js handler](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html).

```
exports.myHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    callback(null, "Hello, world!");
}
```

Lambda functions can also [return binary data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) and  work well with static storage systems like [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/). For example, the function can be run in response to the [creation of static assets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

      const pathName =url.parse(req.url).pathname;
      if (pathName == '/something') {
          res.end('Hello World\n');
      } else {
          res.end('Please visit /something \n');
      }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

You should run your file with `node youfile.js` And when you do `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000` you will see

> Please visit /something

But when you do `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/something` you will see

> Hello World